# Save object if necessary, otherwise use existing

Tags: django, django-models

There is a `Scheduler` model in my project.  This `Scheduler` model says how often do user wants to do some action with an item. There may be many items and users so I want to spare some space and querying times.

Each item has one `Scheduler` object assigned to itself.

```
class Scheduler(models.Model):
    monday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tuesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wednesday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thursday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    friday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    saturday = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sunday = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    hour_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_5 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_6 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_7 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_8 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_9 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_10 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_11 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_12 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_13 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_14 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_15 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_16 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_17 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_18 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_19 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_20 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_21 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_22 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_23 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hour_24 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        scheduler = Scheduler.objects.filter(**{x:y for x,y in self.__dict__.iteritems() if x.startswith('hour') or x.endswith('day')})
        if scheduler:
            return scheduler
        super(Scheduler, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When user creates a new item and sets schedule, I want Django to check, whether there exists such Scheduler object. If yes, don't create new Scheduler with same attributes, instead of that assign existing object to this item. This can be done overriding the `save` method.

The problem is when `User` wants to update the `Scheduler`. I want `Scheduler` not to be updated. Instead of that, there should be created new `Scheduler` because the old scheduler could be in use by another items.

What should I add to my `save` method?

Comment: Are you looking for [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)?

Comment: 24 columns to represent each hour? Surely that's 23 columns too many

Comment: @Sayse In fact, yes, I can use it. Thanks

Comment: @e4c5 Could you elaborate it please? I don't understand what's wrong with that. Yes, it is too many columns but the schedule can be set for multiple hours in day. 1am, 5am, 10 pm etc.

Comment: In most cases you can just use a DateTime field and create multiple entries if a user wants something done multiple times a day. In your present form you have to check 24 columns in each of your query.

Comment: @e4c5 Thank you for your opinion. I've posted the problem with the schedule model at codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146210/storing-scheduling-for-users-in-django-database